# C# Razor Variable not being passed to HTML Tag (ASP.NET Core MVC app)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/shadowwolf123987/Gun-Identification-App

I am attempting to pass the values of two C# variables from the code block defined in my view to the html tags inside of the same view but the values are not being passed to the html tags.

The problem is in the `GunView.cshtml` file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using Azure.Core;
@System;
@System.Web;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

@{
    string name = (string)ViewBag.name;
    string image = (string)ViewBag.image;

    Console.WriteLine(image);
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

<body>
    <div>
        <img src="@image">
        <h1>@name</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Neither the image nor name variable are passed to the html tags and are left blank. But the write lines correctly output the values of the variables and when changing the name variable to a string
(EG. string name = "test";), it is correctly displayed in the html tag.

Comment: For it to be a proper Razor page, you need a `@page` directive at the top. Also: if you replace the value of `name` with a direct literal string, the code works just fine - so most likely, the `ViewBag` just doesn't contain what you think it does .... and also - those two lines `@System; @System.Web;` don't make any sense - did you intend to do a `using` on those two namespaces?

Comment: @marc_s I am unaware of what a page directive is but I've never needed them before and after looking them up, I'm not sure why they would be needed. The Console.WriteLines in the code though show that the ViewBag contains the value that I'm expecting. Also, the two usings were auto-generated I think but I'm pretty sure they aren't needed.

Comment: @Jackdaw The HTMl has all the generated tags but it hasn't got the values except for the TEST header. I am on version 6.0.15.

Comment: @Jackdaw Resulted in a Blank White screen with only the TEST header in black.

Comment: @Jackdaw Thanks for your help, I managed to resolve the answer thanks to the help of another user. Answer has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer supplied by Reddit user @XRay2212xray on my Reddit post, I was able to solve the issue. Thanks all for your assistance and help. https://www.reddit.com/r/programminghelp/comments/15pyid0/trying_to_use_c_razer_variable_in_html_tag_aspnet/

His answer:

The issue is that you are using an Ajax call to invoke the url and then redirecting the user to the same url. The ajax call is passing the value of gun but the redirect isn't, so when you redirect, the value of gun is empty rather then "handguns" so you aren't going into the code that sets the viewbag. You can fix it by adding ?gun=" + gun to the window.location.href as noted below:

```
function sendView() {
        var gun = document.getElementById("guns").value
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Main/GunView",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                gun: gun
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = "/Main/GunView?gun=" + gun
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <img src="@ViewBag.image">
       <h1>@ViewBag.name</h1>
```

Comment: I tried this but it still isnt showing anything.

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.